# Develop on App Server or WFE

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, oracle

I'm developing custom code through VS, Should VS be installed on the WFE or APP Server, remembering I can have more than 1 APP/WFE server. 
I also want to install Oracle connector (I need to connect Oracle DB), which server(s) should this be installed on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Development best to have only one machine, then you can debug the WebApp/Site scoped solutions and as well as any of the timerjobs (which will run on the APp server) if you want to have 2 machines in you dev enviroment, best to have VS on both of them.